# How to finish my report?

Tags: professionalism, communication, management, unprofessional-behavior, pressure

I need some advice since the advice I have so far received from my friend can be considered dangerous. I was finishing up my report and although I was late my supervisor accepted the report. The problem is that I made a few changes to the report which I didn't incorporate within my presentation and forgot to add a few things within the report. Now I want to make these amendments, however after talking with my supervisor she said I had submitted my report and I could not revise it. My friend suggested that I re-upload the report and presentation with the updated amendments. I am confused, I want to finish my report to the best of my abilities, however I don't want to break my supervisor's trust. What do I do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the workplace. In any case, we can't tell you what you should do. You need to be an adult and make your own decisions, and be accountable for those decisions.

Comment: Supervisor referring to an academic supervisor? is this taking place at work or in college? If the latter then as Gregory said we don't handle those environments.

Comment: Echoing Lilienthal and Gregory if this is an *academic* setting such as school or college (which it sounds like) then we can't really address that here - but [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place to look instead.

Comment: Supervisor said no. Do not upload. If you re-upload against her express recommendation, and you are found out, this will be an assessment offence. If the presentation happens afterwards and differs, you can highlight the deviations in the presentation (if such deviations are permitted). If they are not permitted, don't make them.

Answer (score 2):

Your supervisor may have already marked the report you submitted, so reuploading may make no difference. It will probably be time-stamped, so it will be obvious if he does check, and he's told you not to, so don't.

If you give a presentation in the future, it's OK to talk about new information or corrections but you should make it clear that it is a change and why. If you just contradict your report you look like you don't know what you're talking about. If you say "I've since discovered X, which has changed my view about Y" you should pick up some extra marks.

Answer (score 1):

You submitted late - this implies poor planning.

Your supervisor has been generous in allowing a late submission, although you don’t mention if there are any penalties.

Why would you expect to be able to change a submission at all, whether late or not? Your supervisor has clearly told you that you cannot make changes.

When you present be careful of discrepancies - they are easily noticed and may cost you in points or trust or respect.